# Obtener contenido de un div Angular

Tags: html5, angular

Quisiera saber si alguien tiene idea de como obtener el contenido dentro de una etiqueta div en Angular, estuve revisando el concepto de property binding pero no se si pueda usar a la inversa con [innerHTML], ejemplo

Este es el codigo en el componente html:

```
 <div class="">{{dato.numero}}</div>
```

Necesito obtener el dato que esta interpolado ahi como ven es el resultado de una lista, he intentado con Local Reference pero me sale undefined.

Gracias por su atencion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres obtener instancias de elementos nativos puedes usar una `template variable` para utilizar su nombre como selector, usando (`#`).

```
<div #numero>{{dato.numero}}</div>
```

el la logica de tu componente con el decorador `@ViewChild` defines el componente

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
...
export class TuComponente implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('numero', { static: false }) numero: ElementRef; 
...
}
```

ahora puedes obtener su valor:

```
this.numero.nativeElement.value
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!